# Read tables from pdf

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, pdf, datatables

Im trying to read different tables from a pfd in python

I have tried in PyPdf and tabula, but it dosnt work,

this is the link of the pdf: https://www.motor.com.co/uploads/files/2020/05/14/importados-final-%20746.pdf

I need to read each table in a Dataframe, can someone help me?

Or if some one knows other program where i can do it easily i really aprreciated

Comment: Try using camelot. https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Comment: When you say, I have tried and it doesnt work but show us nothing of what you have tried or expand upon why things have not worked. You are not giving us much to help you with. [ask]